# How do I prevent Hibernate from deleting child objects not present in a JSON post?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA `Property` entity that has children (multiple `Rate`'s and multiple `Reservation`'s). In my JavaScript application, I pull `JSON` via `REST` `{property:{rates:[...], reservations[...]}`. Rates and Reservations are very verbose, so when I post a property update (like changing the name), I delete the rates and reservations from the `JSON POST` payload. I hoped that Hibernate would simply ignore the missing keys, but alas, it's removing all the children on save. How do I specify to Hibernate to ignore them if they're not there?

```
@Entity
public class Property {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "property", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<SeasonRate> rates = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "property", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Reservation> reservations = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Ps: My understanding of cascades is limited, but I do actually want the functionality that if someone deletes a property, it must delete the rates and reservations. Nowhere do I update rates or reservations via a full property save though, so perhaps I should just use CASCADE=UPDATE? Rates have their own update mechanism and so do reservations.

Comment: How is the JSON unmarshalled  to the Entity?

Comment: @AlanHay, using the default Jackson Marshaller with Spring Boot

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, however if you are using a Spring MVC Rest controller to handle the update rather than a Spring Data Rest controller then it would appear the former does not support partial updates/patch requests.

Working with traditional non-restful web apps modifying entities directly via a form this is of course possible. For example:

```
@RequestMapping
public String updateEntity(@ModelAttribute myEntity){
  //submitted form parameters merged to existing entity 
  //loaded via getMyEntity() leaving unmodified fields as they were
}

@ModelAttribute
public MyEntity getMyEntity(){
  //load some existing entity
}
```

However when binding JSON to an Entity via @RequestBody this is not possible:

```
@RequestMapping
public String updateEntity(@RequestBody myEntity){
  //new instance instantiated by the Jackson mapper
  //missing fields will be null
}
```

There are some outstanding JIRAs around this:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13127

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10552

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13127

And various SO questions:

[Spring Partial Update Object Data Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124858/spring-partial-update-object-data-binding)

**The good news however is that Spring Data Rest does support partial updates via patch** so  if it is an option to  expose your repository as a Rest Repository then you should be able to achieve the required behaviour:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

> PUT replaces an entire record. Fields not supplied will be replaced
>   with null. **PATCH can be used to update a subset of items**.