# How to solve the value of not null in database when JPA is updating？

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

```
CREATE TABLE `user_info` (
`user_info_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nickname` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) 
)
```

this my database table，database have A record  id=1, nickname=test, email=null

```
UserInfo info = new UserInfo();
info.setUserInfoId(1);
info.setEmail("hello@hotmail.com");
```

When I update with the above code, an error Column 'nickname' cannot be null occurs！

I know this is because JPA has to perform a lookup first, but I don't want to give JPA all the values that can't be empty when updating the operation.

Additional explanation:

Assuming that my front end only sends me ID and email, how can I update it? Use SQL is feasible, but JPA must require nickname not null

How to solve this problem?
thx

Comment: That's not an update operation you show.

Comment: my mistake. I added some descriptions.

Comment: If you need to update an existing entity instance, retrieve the record as suggested below by David Conrad.

Comment: This is really a question about patching an existing entity. Further to my comment below I have also come across: https://cassiomolin.com/2019/06/10/using-http-patch-in-spring/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to update an existing record is to load the record, update any columns that need updating, and then save it, ***not*** by creating a new object.

```
UserInfo info = userInfoRepository.findById(1);
info.setEmail("hello@hotmail.com");
userInfoRepository.save(info);
```

Comment: In JPA, it's not necessary to explicitly save.

Comment: Assuming that my front end only sends me ID and email, how can I update it? Use SQL is feasible, but JPA must require nickname not null

Comment: You'd need to handle that yourself. Assuming you have a Spring MVC controller to handle the request then last time I looked did not support patch operations i.e. partial update. However the Spring Data Rest extension does. See further: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37681555/how-do-i-prevent-hibernate-from-deleting-child-objects-not-present-in-a-json-pos/39424421#39424421. So one option is to delete your controller and use the SDR auto generated endpint for basic CRUD.

Comment: @BOOOMr.Z All you need is ID and email. You look up the existing record by ID, you set the email, and you save it. It already has the nickname on it.